# Transparent Curtains issues

Tags: transparency, 3d, 3ds-max

I have made a curtain with max cloth modifier. Before simulating the cloth i have uvd the plane that i wanted to transform in a curtain.

Now when i use a shader with opacity on it artifacts appear. Looks like a normals issue, but after resetting them i still got this issue. See picture what is going on. 
Anyone can hlp me out? I also get same result when importing in UE4 and use proper material for it.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Im working in 3DsMax by the way

Comment: You're best off posting this question on the Blender stack, from our meta discussions it doesn't look like 3d is acceptable here.

Comment: @johnp: I do not think they will be happy about 3DSmax questions on [blender.se]. However, [a proposal for a 3D-graphics site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics) is now in commitment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because it is using a 3D software and not about graphic design.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft yeah I commented before the OP stated the software. If all else fails the blender chatroom is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

This looks like what's known as Z-fighting, where two parts of the falling curtain are folding back over on each other, and ever so slightly going in and out of each other on their way down the screen, or existing in exactly the same "z" space.

It's not necessarily in the Z space, this is just the name for this result from overlapping or otherwise existing in the same space, for different parts of a model, or two models having aligned parts in the same space.

The best way to deal with this is to spread out the clumping of the curtain to prevent this from happening. A little to the left of your highlighted error is the same thing happening again. So it's only twice, meaning a small change to the clumping of the curtain should stop it.

Comment: on closer inspection, there seems to be a few instances of this happening, and it definitely looks a LOT like z-fighting. I'm nearly sure that's the problem.

Comment: This was going to be my best guess too.